# Ajax запрос error

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Добрый день. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("test.json") 
    .success(function() {alert("успех");})
    .error(function() {alert("ошибка");})
```

После выполнения кода выводится алерт ошибки, а в консоли появляется ошибка

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Почитав форумы, я понял, что проблема в том, что ajax обращается к серверу, но не находит его, так как тестирую я это на ноутбуке. Вопрос: как правильно сделать обращение к локальному файлу на диске (`file:///C:/workspace/test.json`), не прибегая при этом к использованию сервера? И нужно ли потом, при размещении на сервере, возвращаться к первоначальному варианту? Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: никак, для ajax запроса нельзя использовать схему  file

Comment: хмм.. тогда каким образом делается дебаг? Непосредственно на самом сервере?

Comment: есть [ответ для ангуляра](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538301/186999) но суть та же: разворачиваешь локальный сервер у себя и на нем уже открываешь страничку

Comment: спасибо, попробую